# Azure API 'forgets' default group

Tags: azure

As you can see below, I create a group, and then try and create a k8s cluster in this group, getting an error that 'default' doesn't exist. If i then wait another 15 minutes, the error changes. The 'DefaultResourceGroup-CCA' exists immediately, but not as 'defaultresourcegroup-cca', is this case sensitive?

Do you have a suggestion for either of these two errors?

If i delete the '--enable-addons monitoring', the 2nd error goes away, and it works (as long as I have waited ~15 minutes after the group create).

```
$ az group create --name socks --location canadacentral
{
  "id": "/subscriptions/187362fc-9705-4173-9056-6bd387695cf0/resourceGroups/socks",
  "location": "canadacentral",
  "managedBy": null,
  "name": "socks",
  "properties": {
    "provisioningState": "Succeeded"
  },
  "tags": null
}
don@cube:~/src-ag/corp-tools/gitlab-runner$ az group list
[
  {
    "id": "/subscriptions/187362fc-9705-4173-9056-6bd387695cf0/resourceGroups/DefaultResourceGroup-CCA",
    "location": "canadacentral",
    "managedBy": null,
    "name": "DefaultResourceGroup-CCA",
    "properties": {
      "provisioningState": "Succeeded"
    },
    "tags": null
  },
  {
    "id": "/subscriptions/187362fc-9705-4173-9056-6bd387695cf0/resourceGroups/socks",
    "location": "canadacentral",
    "managedBy": null,
    "name": "socks",
    "properties": {
      "provisioningState": "Succeeded"
    },
    "tags": null
  }
]
don@cube:~/src-ag/corp-tools/gitlab-runner$ az aks create --resource-group socks --name sock-shop --node-count 1 --node-vm-size Standard_F4s_v2 --enable-addons monitoring --generate-ssh-keys
Resource group 'defaultresourcegroup-cca' could not be found.
don@cube:~/src-ag/corp-tools/gitlab-runner$ az aks create --resource-group socks --name sock-shop --node-count 1 --node-vm-size Standard_F4s_v2 --enable-addons monitoring --generate-ssh-keys
Operation failed with status: 'Bad Request'. Details: Unable to get log analytics workspace info. Resource ID: /subscriptions/187362fc-9705-4173-9056-6bd387695cf0/resourcegroups/defaultresourcegroup-cca/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/defaultworkspace-187362fc-9705-4173-9056-6bd387695cf0-cca. Detail: operationalinsights.WorkspacesClient#GetSharedKeys: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=404 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=404 Code="ResourceNotFound" Message="The Resource 'Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/defaultworkspace-187362fc-9705-4173-9056-6bd387695cf0-cca' under resource group 'defaultresourcegroup-cca' was not found."
```

Answer (score 0):

We are currently experiencing an outage in South Central US that is affecting ARM
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/
[image]

You will want to monitor the Azure Status Page for further updates. Unfortunately we cannot do anything until the problem has been mitigated by engineering.